# Weighting a regression CNN for imbalanced data?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network, data-science

I have a CNN for regression that takes an image and outputs a float 0-10. My model is doing okay, but I have a serious problem with imbalanced data, making my model predict between 6-8 for almost all images, but achieving a decent mean squared error. I know of people weighting their classes based on how imbalanced their dataset is. So, is there a way to do this with a regression model? If it helps, my output is a float, but all of my data is in intervals of 0.5 in the 0-10 range, so there are in a way 20 different classes. Here is the distribution of my data labels.

[image]

I understand there are other methods such as:

- Oversampling the minority group.
- Using data augmentation to make "copies" of the minority group.
- Optimizing a different performance metric. (No idea what that would be)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your data might have originally represented a regression problem, but after binning it into 20 groups you are training your model on a **20-class classification problem**. Thus you should treat it as such and look for finding ways to combat this imbalance. The most prevalent ways are:

- **oversampling** the minority class(es)
- **undersampling** the majority class(es)
- using **class weights**

I'm usually prefer the first, because models tend to do better with more data, but the third is simpler to implement and doesn't add an extra computation cost to the training.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean with it being like a 20 class classification, but are you saying I should turn my model into a classification model or just treat it as such. I am just confused on how to add class weights when there aren't technically classes.

Comment: As it is you **are** using a classification model and in the model's eyes it sees just a classification task. Since your model is treating outputs as classes, you should use class weights like you would in a classification task. If it were a regression task it wouldn't be much difference; what "class" weights do is that they tell the model to **pay more attention** to some samples more than other, depending on their target. Even if you had a regression task you could use "class" weights. The difference is that the weight wouldn't depend on the class but its continuous label.

Comment: I found the weights for the different classes and put it as a parameter for `class_weights` as shown here: `model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=100, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("./model.ckpt", monitor='mean_squared_error', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)], class_weight=class_weights)` Although it does display the weighted mean squared error, it still optimizes based on the unweighted mean squared error. Am I missing something or do I have to write a custom loss function?

Comment: No, that's what you want. If you used the unweighted MSE it would have no difference that previous. After it finishes training on the weighted MSE, evaluate it on a regular MSE to see if it improved.

Answer (score 1):

One popular technique for over-sampling is [SMOTE](https://jair.org/index.php/jair/article/view/10302).

As for optimizing a different metric, one option is to optimize a weighted loss where the weights are proportional to the inverse of the class representation.

Comment: Does tensorflow or keras have a built in way to make a custom metric or is that totally a manual process?

Comment: This is a regression problem, so what would be the inverse of the class representation?

Comment: Indeed, as implied above, SMOTE is for classification problems only, and it is not applicable to regression ones (like here).